# Swipe wrapper prevents all click events on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using `http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/` plugin for touch events.
Main problem is when I attach swipe event on wrapper element, all other events are prevented. Work on desktop browser but not on ipad.

I tried with stop propagation on target element but still have a problem.

```
_pager.prototype.initialize = function () {
    "use strict";
    var base = this;
    //cursorPosition();

    base.$container.swipe({
        swipeUp   : function (e, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            if ($(event.target).hasClass('inner-wrapper')) {

                base.$container.transition({ y : -674 }, 500, 'out')
            }

        },
        swipeDown : function (e, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {

            if ($(event.target).hasClass('inner-wrapper')) {
                base.$container.transition({ y : 0 }, 500, 'out')
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with css class noSwipe which excluded elements for swipe.